# How to program microcontrollers

Tags: c++, python, programming-languages, microcontroller

Hi i'm wanting to program microcontrollers but i don't really know how to do it and what i need to do it. I have no idea where to look in the slightest for the information i need. I've been coding with python for around 11 months now and i know how to use the language well. I've used c++ in the past and i know quite a large amount of that language too.

When programming microcontrollers can the microcontroller be programmed with any coding language or do microcontrollers only allow certain languages to be used with it?

I have endless amount of questions but i'm not going to ask them all, if someone could please point me in the right direction i would be very grateful. Thanks.

Comment: Micro_processors_ are what power your PC and laptop, e.g. They can be programmed in any language the operating system supports. Do you probably mean micro_controllers_ (like Arduino boards)?

Comment: Subject to availability, almost ALL processors can be programmed in almost any language... Your question doesn't make much sense...

Comment: Sorry yeah what i meant was micro controllers, like to do something basic to start like making an LED flash etc. I just don't know everything i need to program a micro controller. @Dubu

Comment: @user2387537 I modified your question accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is with the word "programmed". Microprocessors (you mean CPUs, right?) typically execute *machine codes* which are specific to their *hardware* platform.  Machine codes are just bytes read from the memory and interpreted in a special way.  This is the lowest possible level at which processors may be programmed (and some day the were programmed that way).

Now since programming processors this way is very inconvenient, the so-called "assembly languages" have been invented. Basically, they just define symbolic representations for machine codes and sets of rules of their interpretation. Then a special program, called translator, takes a set of text files containing the definition of a program written in an assembly language and produces *something* which contains machine codes and might be executed by the target processor. (The definition of this "something" is hard, and let's not digress.)

Now there's another level higher up — languages like `C` (and, to a lesser extent, `C++`) which try to abstract away the details of a particular hardware platform and allow to concentrate on *algorithms* and data formats rather than dealing with a particular processor. Obviously, this moves the knowledge of a particular H/W platform to the *compiler* — a program which takes the text of your program written in a high-level language and produces something runnable by a target processor.

Now there's another level higher up which includes languages which almost completely abstract you away from any particularities of a H/W platform.  JavaScript which runs in your browser when you're reading Stack Overflow is a good example — the programs in it are still executed by the processor of the device running your browser but there are many complicated layers of code between those JS scripts and the processor.

By now you should see that there's no definitive answer to your question. If you would like to dabble with low-level code for the CPU on your bedroom PC then google for "x86 assembler", "intel assembler" etc. [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_assembly_language) is a good start. If you want to program some other processor, the search query to use would be similar. If, instead, you want to program some specialized processor like [AVR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmel_AVR) then start with that product manuals as they usually come with specialized tools.

Answer (score 1):

if you are interested in getting handy with basic practical like you said "like to do something basic to start like making an LED flash etc."

choose basic micro controller, say from 8051 family we will take 89c51(NXP/Atmel depend on availability). Go through the user manual first, it will give you brief idea(*overall architecture*) about it.
regarding programming you will find basic code for LED flash in manual only(likely).
if you are using NXP micro-controller then ***Flashmagic*** software is freely available on internet you can download it.
In you IDE(like keil) do not forget to create "**.hex** " file after you are done with your coding.
now open Flashmagic and load your **.hex** file in it and burn your micro controller for particular code you wrote.

Good Luck!!